# ROS Answers SE migration: tf tree setup

Tags: navigation, ros-kinetic, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

I am new to ros and I want to use the robot_localization package to estimate the state of my real-life 2D robot and then use the navigation package to navigate the robot. My question is if the robot_localization package already provide a tf tree or do I have to set it up by myself? I am using Python to build my files. I already followed the TF-tutorials for Python but I am still confused how to set up the tree. I understand you have a broadcaster and a listener but how can I connect the frames provided by the robot_localization package? When launching "ekf_template.launch" and then doing "rosrun tf view_frames" i get "no tf data received". In the navigation package, there is a map provided by the map_server.

Kind regards,
Stef

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/286040/tf-tree-setup/) by [Stef_Boat](https://answers.ros.org/users/34241/stef_boat/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2018-03-20

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-03-20**:
You have multiple questions here. You should edit this question or break it into several different ones...

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2018-03-21**:
You "setup" the tf tree within the urdf of your robot specifying all its joints and links then the node `robot_state_publisher` and `joint_state_publisher` do the work. Check [#q212525](https://answers.ros.org/question/212525/understanding-tf-urdf-and-static_transform_publisher/) for more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The only transform that the state estimation nodes in `r_l` will produce will be from your world frame (e.g., *odom*) to your robot's body frame (e.g. *base_link*).

The state estimation nodes assume that you have provided a transform from any sensor data that you provide to one of those frames, or that your data is already *in* one of those frames. For example, if you fuse velocity data from wheel encoders, it needs to be in the *base_link* frame (your robot's body frame), *or* you need to provide a transform from your wheel encoder frame to the *base_link* frame.

If you have some kind of absolute pose measurement (from, say, overhead cameras that are localizing your robot), the output of that pose data needs to be in the *odom* frame, or you have to provide a transform from the camera pose data to the *odom* frame.

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2018-04-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3